# Suspender Trigger mediante condicional

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Eu não encontrei um statenment SQL `IF` no SQLite e o mais proximo foi o `CASE`, que esta me atendendo, entretanto gostaria de suspender uma trigger mediante uma condicional e acredito que só pode ser feito com `IF`

```
CREATE TRIGGER...
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATA < 900) THEN
       SUSPEND;

    ...
END;
```

É possível fazer algo assim no SQLite?

Comment: Não assim do jeito que você está querendo. As triggers só tem comandos de DML. O melhor que eu já fiz foi por a condição em todo e qualquer `where` das queries da trigger

Comment: Pensei nisso mas seria um {IF} para definir de faço ou não um {INSERT} ou seja na trigger o {INSERT} só poderia ser executado se atender a condicional e não vejo onde colocar um {WHERE} nesse caso.

Comment: tem uma construção que é o `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, onde o `SELECT` é uma seleção tradicional. Infelizmente não tem `IF` nem variáveis no SQLite, não dá para programar muita coisa

Comment: Será que no WHEN da trigger é possível fazer duas condições, hoje eu já tenho um AFTER UPDATE ... WHEN campo = 1. Ai poderia colocar um SELECT COUNT(*)... >= 900

Comment: nunca vi `WHEN` na gramática do SQLite para triggers. Talvez falta de atenção minha

Comment: Obrigado pelo brainstorm Jefferson.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
AFTER UPDATE ON table WHEN NEW.field = 1
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Também pode ser feito com mais de uma condicional:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
AFTER UPDATE ON table WHEN NEW.field = 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) >= 900
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Para SQL genérico, você pode usar CASE:
`CASE` é usado para fornecer tipo de lógica `if-then-else` para SQL. Sua sintaxe é:

```
SELECT CASE ("column_name")
  WHEN "condition1" THEN "result1"
  WHEN "condition2" THEN "result2"
  ...
  [ELSE "resultN"]
  END
FROM "table_name"
```

Exemplo:

```
UPDATE pages
SET rkey = rkey + 2,
    lkey = CASE  WHEN lkey >= $key THEN lkey + 2 ELSE lkey END
WHERE rkey >= $key
```

Link da documentação: [Aqui](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Outros Links que explicam bem: [sqlite.awardspace.info](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg09.htm)  e  ["Usando expressões CASE ao modificar dados"](http://www.craigsmullins.com/ssu_0899.htm)